# IBM Cognos Report Studio - how to remove time from a date field

Tags: report, cognos

I have a field in a complicated cognos report that populates the timestamp with the date, but I do not see any formatting laid on top of this field. How Do I remove the timestamp from the date?

This is what I am looking at:

```
[Project Header].[Project Start Date]
```

Answer (score 1):

The formatting is being done when you drag your data item ([Project Header].[Project Start Date]) into data container (list, crosstab, chart,...).
When you click on the data item inside the container (make sure you click the actual data item and not the header) look for the Data Format in the properties window:
[image]
Then just choose Date from the format type combobox:
[image]
Additional option would be cast the actual data item to date:

```
cast([Project Header].[Project Start Date], date)
```

Answer (score 1):

So I ran into a similar issue myself when trying to remove the time element from a report i created. Unfortunately, the version of Cognos my company uses no longer has date available in data format under properties.

To resolve the issue, I used Cast([Project Header].[Project start date], date) to remove the time element. In inputted the cast element as part of my column selection.

[Cognos_Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLJkN.png)

[Cognos_Cast_Element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QhWkU.png)

Comment: After further reviewing and digging into the matter, if you click the data column as opposed to the header, in the properties to the right, under Data, look for Data format -> click the 3 ellipses and you're able to change data classification under format type.